# How to convert an array of UTC dates into milliseconds using JS/Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I'm having an array of dates:

```
var ticks = [];
ticks = [Tue Jan 01 2013 00:00:00 GMT-0800 (PST), Fri Feb 01 2013 00:00:00 GMT-0800 (PST), Fri Mar 01 2013 00:00:00 GMT-0800 (PST), Mon Apr 01 2013 00:00:00 GMT-0700 (PDT), Wed May 01 2013 00:00:00 GMT-0700 (PDT), Sat Jun 01 2013 00:00:00 GMT-0700 (PDT), Mon Jul 01 2013 00:00:00 GMT-0700 (PDT), Thu Aug 01 2013 00:00:00 GMT-0700 (PDT), Sun Sep 01 2013 00:00:00 GMT-0700 (PDT)].
```

How can I convert the above array of dates into millisecond format:
something like below:

```
[1390000000000, 1395000000000, 1400000000000, 1405000000000, 1410000000000, 1415000000000]
```

(PS: I need this format as I have a function that takes this format to display the x-axis)

Any ideas on how this can be achieved? Thanks!!!!

Comment: Are those strings or Date objects in `ticks`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simply map a new array from the date objects:

```
ticks.map(function ( value ) {
    return value.getTime();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you will get the raw data in string format, or else you have a bit of todo

```
var ticks = ... // raw data
var t2 = [];
for ( var i = 0; i < ticks.length; ++i ) {
    t2.push( new Date(ticks[i]).getTime() );
}
```

Comment: this one worked as well! wish could do more than one green ticks..:)